# ComboBox not updating when ObservableCollection is modified in another View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I am working on a little MVVM WPF project for practicing purposes and I have two windows with one view for each, one for displaying employees (`MainWindow`) and one for adding employees (`AddPersonWindow`).

In my MainWindow, there is a  ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection and I can open the `AddPersonWindow` from a button in my `MainWindow`. However, if I add an employee to the ObservableCollection from the `AddPersonWindow` by clicking on the save button and executing the `AddPerson()` function, the ComboBox in the MainWindow is not updating. If I execute the very same `AddPerson()` function from the `MainWindow`, everything is fine and the ComboBox shows the new entry. What am I missing here?

Code:

Person.cs

```
class Person
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return String.Format("{0}, {1}", Name, Surname); } }
}
```

PersonViewModel.cs

```
class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public CommandHandler ButtonClick { get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        CreatePerson();
    }       

    //Combobox SelectedItem
    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }

        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }      



    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();



    public void CreatePerson()
    {     


        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\some_file.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            string[] substrings = line.Split(',');
            Person person = new Person {
                Surname = substrings[0],
                Name = substrings[1],
                Street = substrings[2],
                HouseNumber = substrings[3],
                PostalCode = substrings[4],
                City = substrings[5],
                PhoneAreaCode = substrings[6],
                PhoneNumber = substrings[7],
                Email = substrings[8] };
                PersonList.Add(person);
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


}
```

AddPersonViewModel.cs

```
class AddPersonViewModel : PersonViewModel
{


    public AddPersonViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new CommandHandler(AddPerson);
    }

    public string EnteredSurname { get; set; }
    public string EnteredName { get; set; }
    public string EnteredStreet { get; set; }
    public string EnteredHouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string EnteredCity { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnteredEmail { get; set; }



    public void AddPerson()
    {


        Person person = new Person
        {
            Surname = EnteredSurname,
            Name = EnteredName,
            Street = EnteredStreet,
            HouseNumber = EnteredHouseNumber,
            PostalCode = EnteredPostalCode,
            City = EnteredCity,
            PhoneAreaCode = EnteredPhoneAreaCode,
            PhoneNumber = EnteredPhoneNumber,
            Email = EnteredEmail
        };
        PersonList.Add(person);

    }
}
```

CommandHandler.cs

```
class CommandHandler : ICommand
{

    Action ExecuteHandler;

    public CommandHandler(Action executeHandler)
    {            
        ExecuteHandler = executeHandler;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteHandler();
    }

}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new PersonViewModel();
    }
```

AddPersonWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public AddPersonWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new AddPersonViewModel();
    }
```

ComboBox in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ComboBox Width="325" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="FullName" IsEditable="True" />
```

Button in AddPersonWindow.xaml:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="30" Margin="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="True" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}">Speichern</Button>
```

Comment: Are they using the same instance of `PersonViewModel`? Asuming that you are creating multiple `PersonViewModel/AddPersonViewModel` so you have multiple instances of `PersonList`. You should create one `AddPersonViewModel` and pass the instance to the other pages/windows. _(via constructor)_

Comment: I think you brought me on the right track. Must be because I create a `PersonViewModel` and an `AddPersonViewModel` in the code-behind (I added both code-behind files in the original post) and thus two separate `PersonList` instances are created. 
Though I still haven't found a solution how to deal with this - will keep trying!

Comment: Yep, they don't share their `PersonList` thats why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to share one `PersonList` instance to be shared between the tow view models, so I have decided to edit the underlying CSV file directly in the `AddPersonViewModel`:

```
 class AddPersonViewModel
{

    public CommandHandler ButtonClick { get; set; }


    public AddPersonViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClick = new CommandHandler(AddPerson);
    }

    public string EnteredSurname { get; set; }
    public string EnteredName { get; set; }
    public string EnteredStreet { get; set; }
    public string EnteredHouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string EnteredCity { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPhoneAreaCode { get; set; }
    public string EnteredPhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EnteredEmail { get; set; }



    void AddPerson()
    {

        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\some_file.csv", "\r\n" + 
            EnteredSurname + "," +
            EnteredName + "," +
            EnteredStreet + "," +
            EnteredHouseNumber + "," +
            EnteredPostalCode + "," +
            EnteredCity + "," +
            EnteredPhoneAreaCode + "," +
            EnteredPhoneNumber + "," +
            EnteredEmail,
            Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
            );

    }
}
}
```

To refresh the ComboBox in the view of the `PersonViewModel` class after a person was added in the other view, I implemented a method that can be executed by clicking on a button. For this, I use the follwoing method:

```
public void RefreshPersons()
    {

        PersonList.Clear();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\c.philipp\Downloads\adressbuch.csv", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            string[] substrings = line.Split(',');
            Person person = new Person
            {
                Surname = substrings[0],
                Name = substrings[1],
                Street = substrings[2],
                HouseNumber = substrings[3],
                PostalCode = substrings[4],
                City = substrings[5],
                PhoneAreaCode = substrings[6],
                PhoneNumber = substrings[7],
                Email = substrings[8]
            };
            PersonList.Add(person);
        }


    }
```